# make is ignoring some depedencies

Tags: makefile

Here is my Makefile:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -std=gnu99
OBJ1=mknlrescs.o collisionsys.o csheader.o utils.o labels.o csdata.o 
OBJ2=mknrescs.o utils.o

all: mknlrescs mknrescs

mknlrescs: $(OBJ1)
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

mknrescs: $(OBJ2)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

%.o: %.c %.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<
```

When I type `make mknlrescs` I get the following:

```
$ make mknlrescs
gcc -Wall -std=gnu99   -c -o mknlrescs.o mknlrescs.c
gcc -Wall -std=gnu99 -c collisionsys.c
gcc -Wall -std=gnu99 -c csheader.c
gcc -Wall -std=gnu99 -c utils.c
gcc -Wall -std=gnu99 -c labels.c
gcc -Wall -std=gnu99 -c csdata.c
gcc -Wall -std=gnu99 -o mknlrescs mknlrescs.o -lm
mknlrescs.o: In function `main':
mknlrescs.c:(.text+0x4b): undefined reference to...
```

And a bunch of other "undefined reference to..." errors.

The rest of the objects are not being linked.  Notice it only linked the first object file.   How can I correct this?

Answer (score 1):

The automatic variable `$<` stands for the first prerequisite of the rule that defined the recipe.

If you want to use ALL the prerequisites, use `$^` instead.

See [Automatic Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) for a full list.